# Trillian instant messenenger won't install on the new elementary!

Tags: software-installation

I've used Elementary OS Freya for years now, And me and my whole family used an instant messenger called Trillian, And now switching to Loki it won't install. to that I say WTF, why can't we install Trillian on Elementary os Loki?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are referring to the fact that there is no .deb GUI application to handle installs and therefore you cannot just click the .deb file.

I was able to install Trillian without issues by doing the following:

1. Downloading the .deb file from their website:
   https://www.trillian.im/get/linux/2.0/linux.html
2. Using Terminal: `sudo apt install /path/to/file.deb`